# Read from BufferReader and writing into file

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm trying to read a file using (client side):

```
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));            
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(".\\Recibido\\" + recurso);                

while (br.ready()) {
    c = br.read();
    //  System.out.println((char) c);
    fos.write((byte) c);
    fos.flush();

}

fos.close();
```

But instead of getting the bytes on the left, I get the ones on the right:
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmIOr.png)

It is not a problem of sending differents bytes, I know the server side is right because I can read it using different methods, but I have to use this one. My doubt is why am I getting this different? Am I doing a wrong conversion when I use "fos.write((byte)c);"?

Comment: Readers are for reading character streams. You deal with a byte stream, so better use a `BufferedInputStream` instead.

Comment: br.read() returns an int. The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. Whereas, byte has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Comment: If I use BufferedInputStream and .available(), sometimes I don't get the first part of the pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells of a confusion wrt. the encoding. The commentors are right in that you shouldn't be using Readers here, they are for text.

What I suspect is happening is the following:

1. You read the byte stream with a Reader, this is using the system default charset to decode the bytes into chars.
2. Be aware that internally, Java chars are UTF-16
3. When you cast to byte, you truncate part of the UTF-16 value, that's why for more normal characters, you get the right value instead of additional bytes where there should not be one
4. Then you write the truncated UTF-16 value to the output. Obviously you would have to be very lucky for that to be the original value.

Lessons learned:

1. Don't mix Readers/Writers with byte streams.
2. Don't cast char to byte
3. Specify the encoding of your Reader / Writer